# undefined symbol: gluUnProject while running QT application on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt4, ubuntu-12.04, glu

I am using `Qt 5.7.1` and my application have 3 plug-ins.

While running one plug-in which have graphics its crashing immediately by giving error the following error:

```
libSamplePluginD.so.1.0.0: undefined symbol: gluUnProject
```

What may be the problem, Program flow looks correct

Same code works fine in windows

Pro file

```
win32:CONFIG (release, debug|release): LIBS += -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32
else:win32:CONFIG (debug, debug|release): LIBS += -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32

RESOURCES += \
surfacebuilderresource.qrc
```

Comment: [`gluUnProject()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml) is a function of the OpenGL utility library (guessed this from prefix `glu`). For me, it sounds like an unresolved dependency in `libSamplePluginD.so.1.0.0` to `libGLU`. (on Linux probably a `.so`).

Comment: I added library libGLU.so.1.3.1 and created symbolic link, still not working

Comment: I'm not sure about version management of .so-s. (Sorry, I haven't touched any *x anymore for years now.) Tried google "linux trace dynamic link" and found some promising links in the first hits...

Comment: Thanks for your inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

linking libGLU.so worked for me:

`unix: LIBS += -lGLU`